# How to fill a webpage form automatically from a spreadsheet?

Tags: 13.04, firefox, libreoffice

I am working on a form filling process.

Every time, I go to spreadsheet and  copy the data, to paste on web site continuously so I feel bore and wasting time .

I want to automate the process with a simple technique but i know a little bit about imacro tool website [here.](http://wiki.imacros.net/Form_Filling)

I want best solution and simple technique....

Comment: Do you know how to program?

Comment: yeah little bit but i think difficult and thats not direct from spreadsheet

Comment: Captcha are included in html forms to prevent automatic filling.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously your first choice is to use iMacros. But that's not going to have a lot to do with Ubuntu.

If this was my problem, I would sit down and write a Python script. Libraries like [Mechanize](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet/) and [Requests](http://www.python-requests.org) make HTTP automation really simple, and for iterating through the data I'd use [OpenPyXL](https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/) or just export the data to something simple like CSV. If you need to process HTML as well, BeautifulSoup is awesome.

I have written similar tools in less than 50 lines of Python... And whatever the language, this is something a seasoned programmer shouldn't need more than an hour on.

---

There are also Macro recorders available in the repositories (both paid and free). I've no idea how well these work. Search and see.